# "On reality" vs "in reality"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, prepositions

I am not sure of the difference between these two phrases, especially the meaning of *on reality*.

I found the phrase *lost his grip on reality*; can I use *in* instead of *on* in this case?

Answer (score 4):

*On* in this case is tied to *grip*; I could have a grip *on* a baseball bat, but not a grip *in* one.

*In reality* refers to the narrative of it in relation to time.  So no, you must use *on* in the case of your example.

Answer (score 2):

I think, in your example, "on" is used because that is the preposition to use with "grip". It is not about what to use with "reality".